# Membase node fault handeling in Java

Tags: java, memcached, membase

I am looking for a java example that shows how to avoid exceptions with Membase when one of its nodes goes down.

I have a small cluster of two nodes with one 'default' bucket. It is replicated on both servers. I wrote little java test app for stress loading. I use spymemcache 2.7. When I run it - both servers get busy. When I shutdown one membase instance my java app crushes.

Here is exception log:

```
2011-06-15 17:32:33.405 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/192.168.1.9:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2011-06-15 17:32:33.407 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=/192.168.1.10:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2011-06-15 17:32:33.412 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@63238bd2
2011-06-15 17:32:33.413 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@37bd2664
2011-06-15 18:20:21.896 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting due to exception on {QA sa=/192.168.1.9:11211, #Rops=2, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.StoreOperationImpl@5f4275d4, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:237)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:210)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:236)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleReads(MemcachedConnection.java:487)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:427)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:280)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.run(MemcachedClient.java:2063)
2011-06-15 18:20:21.897 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Closing, and reopening {QA sa=/192.168.1.9:11211, #Rops=2, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.StoreOperationImpl@5f4275d4, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=1}, attempt 0.
2011-06-15 18:20:21.898 WARN net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.BinaryMemcachedNodeImpl:  Discarding partially completed op: net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.StoreOperationImpl@5f4275d4
2011-06-15 18:20:21.899 WARN net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.BinaryMemcachedNodeImpl:  Discarding partially completed op: net.spy.memcached.protocol.binary.GetOperationImpl@802b249
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception waiting for value
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1146)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1163)
```

I made node 192.168.1.9 go down, but client didn't understood that and crashed.

Any ideas how to properly handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we didn't find answer for the question and we don't use this software anymore. Now we use Erlang with absolutely illuminates the need in such kind of in-memory data storage.

Answer (score 0):

-Does the exception go away if you fail over the server?
-Which server's URI are you pointing the client at?  Does it make a difference if you point it at the "other" one and/or both of them?

Perry

Answer (score 0):

This I believe is not because of memcached cluster as I had this error message when running a single memcached server on my local and running a test case to cache and retrieve data. Following environment was in use mac snow leapord + spymemcached 2.7 + memcached 1.4.6

I was running it in daemon mode and it got fixed after I restarted my local memcached server.

I am sorry that I cannot exactly tell the cause for this but doing the above fixed the problem.

Comment: Hi Bobby, my question is not related to memcache, it is about membase. But thank you for sharing your experience.